# firebase public directory error

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, github, firebase-hosting

I am trying to upload an updated instance of a website to firebase that I pulled from my collaborator's github repo. I am getting the following error after I use command "firebase deploy":

> === Deploying to 'makany-webapp'...
>
> i  deploying hosting
>
> **Error**: *Specified public directory does not exist, can't deploy hosting*

this is the *firebase.json* content:

```
{
  "hosting": {
      "public": "www",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/public/**",
          "destination": "/public.html"
        },
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to deploy from the directory where the firebase.json resides. This same directory contains a "src" folder which contains the index.html file as well as other folder.

[current directory and src directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P99mO.png)

Comment: I believe I had to change my src folder name to www

Answer (score 0):

my bad. I had to change my src folder name to www